# Angular component's scss overwriting another component's scss (is it a way to force overwrite without viewEncapsulation.None?)

Tags: angular, typescript, sass

I am a junior dev intern at a 15 dev Angular project. They have very limited time to mentor me and I have been set now to do design bugs / scss related tasks. The scss itself is fine. My problem is that the components scss I'm working on is being over-written by a component that also is a table.

[The first two images are the changes to over write the main-table.component (shown last)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfnCp.png)

My supervisor said I had to find a way to do it without using viewEncapsulation.None since it makes scss globally available. The component that are overwriting my target component is nested in a module. I suspect this is a implementation issue as my last task was to redo the projects use of ngx translation module library since it was implementet with a custom module and not the correct way. Are there any way to redirect the styling of my component without making it available globally with viewEncapsulation.None? Any pointers to this problem is greatly appreciated! Thanks

I have tried importing the main-table.component scss into the contact-person-table.component.scss but it didn't work. main-table still over-writes it. I have tried styling every other component that could be related to the contact-person-table. I have tried the magic `!important` without viewEncapsulation.None.

Only using `viewEncapsulation.None` AND `!important` works.

main-table.component:

```
.table {
  width: 100%;
}
.filtering-row {
  width: 100%;
  height: 4rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;

  mat-form-field {
    margin-right: 2rem;
  }
}

.filtering-row *:only-child {
  margin-left: auto;
}

.main-table-container {
  width: 100%;
}

.element-detail {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
}

tr.detail-row {
  height: 0;

  .no-padding {
    padding: 0;
  }
}

th,
td {
  &:not(:first-child) {
    padding-left: 5px;
  }

  &:not(:last-child) {
    padding-right: 5px;
  }

  &.expand-column {
    width: 5rem;
    padding-right: 0;
  }
}

app-main-table-expandable-row {
  width: 100%;
}

.pointer-cursor {
  cursor: pointer;
}

$columns: edit, delete, color, status, actions, confirm;
@each $column in $columns {
  .mat-column-#{$column} {
    flex: 0 0 5%;
    width: 5%;
  }
}

.subheader-row {
  background: var(--main-nav-background-highlight);
}

.sub-header-badge {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 1rem;
  height: 1rem;
  background: var(--font-color-primary);
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: var(--main-background);
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1rem;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  position: relative;
  top: -3px;
}

.sub-header-attributes {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 1.2rem;
  margin: auto;
  height: 0;
  top: calc(50% - 12px);
}

.maintenance-job-group-name-container {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 90%;
}

.maintenance-job-group-name {
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  padding-right: 0.5rem;
  max-width: 40vw;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.maintenance-job-subheader-column {
  position: relative;
}

tr.maintenance-job td.mat-cell.cdk-cell.cdk-column-name.mat-column-name {
  width: 35%;
}

// .expired-due-list {
//   background-color: var(--red-300);
// }

// .expiring-due-list {
//   background-color: var(--yellow-500);
// }

.paginator {
  width: -webkit-fill-available;
}
```

contact-person-table.component:

```
app-contact-person-table {
  .cdk-column-name ~ th,
  td {
    &:not(:first-child) {
      padding-left: 0.625rem !important;
    }

    &:not(:last-child) {
      padding-right: 0.625rem !important;
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

```
::ng-deep app-contact-person-table {
  .main-table-container ~ th,
  td {
    &:not(:first-child) {
      padding-left: 0.625rem !important;
    }

    &:not(:last-child) {
      padding-right: 0.625rem !important;
    }
  }
}
```

This solution workds and avoids the viewEncapsulation.None but still feels silly using ::ng-deep and !important.

Comment: Show us the CSS for both (with code snippets, screenshots of code aren't too helpful). It sounds like you're just being overridden due to selector specificity. Your supervisor is correct in that `viewEncapsulation.None` is generally bad practice and `!important` can become a crutch for not learning proper cascading box model principles.

Comment: Thanks! Added scss for both components

Comment: So the `th,td` css class in the main is overriding the equivalent in the component? You can remove the component element selector it's not necessary (eg; `app-contact-person-table {...}` isn't necessary though you can specify `:host { ... }`) beyond that you'll just have to figure out how to overcome the selector specificity with additional selectors on your component side. Like if you were to add a class to the container of those elements and use it as a parent selector so that your selectors are more specific.

Comment: The issue is not specificity. I tried doing what you said with adding a custom class, even tried custom ID. But I found a solution using ::ng-deep and !important.

This works better than viewEncapsulation.None but still it seem silly having to use ::ng-deep and !important. Didn't work without !important.

Comment: All `ng-deep` does is remove the component selector for that class which is what provides the specificity, eg; when bundled your css for that component gets a UID appended to the front of each class in your component, that's all angular view encapsulation is, when you use `viewEncapsulation.NONE` it's the equivalent except in your case removes it only for that CSS class since used `ng-deep` on it instead of all the css classes in the component css. Either way glad you got a remedy.